# what does this regex mean "[^>]*

Tags: regex

I came across some regex's and this thing got me confusing!
i am not able to understand what exatly it means:

```
[^>]*
```

could anypne please tell me.

Comment: maybe you will read regex documentation?

Comment: Is this some sort of weird smiley?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Match 0 or more characters, which are not `>`. The `^` as the first item in character class `[]` will make the character class a negated character class, and any character after `^` are excluded.

Answer (score 2):

This means any character except for `>` repeated any number of times.

Answer (score 1):

Characters in the Language can repeat any number of times except for `>`.

`^` is an indicator of exclusion.

`*` is an indicator of repetition

```
[^>]*
```

Anything except `>` can repeat

Answer (score 0):

This Pattern will Select anything except `>`